# Fractional Second timeouts with Python MySQLdb connect?

Tags: python, timeout, mysql-python

The MySQLdb.connect() method allows a connect_timeout parameter. I use this in a config screen (in which database parameters are set) to give a live update of whether the current configuration is enabling a successful connection to a database as the use types.

```
import MySQLdb
....
try:
    con = mdb.connect(db_server, username, password, db_name,connect_timeout=1)
    connected=1
except:
    connected=0
```

However the timeout parameter is an integer number of seconds. This does not allow for a responsive user experience. Waiting a second while the system hangs between each key press is not acceptable. 200ms would would ok, but the library doesn't support that.

How could one get a fraction of a second timeout on MySQLdb.connect()?